# How to fix problem with resources on android?

Tags: android, resources, imageview

Getting the following in LogCat:

```
03-28 16:18:57.795: WARN/ResourceType(8351): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000001
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351): Unable to find resource: 1
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:579)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:485)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:270)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewImage(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:217)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:165)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:619)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:280)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-28 16:18:57.865: WARN/ImageView(8351):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Actually, resource files exists (R.drawable.star_on at drawable-hdpi and drawable-ldpi, Eclipse has this value in autocomplete), here is the extract from R.java:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int star_off=0x7f020007;
    public static final int star_on=0x7f020008;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, but the problem was with `setViewValue` function - I was changing `ListView` icon based on DB value and I didn't return `true` there (returned `false`) and hence I was getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning and building the project.

Android is searching the image with id resource **0x00000001**, which is not correct.

If that doesn't works try deleting the "**gen**" folder and building again.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a compilation error. Check your console for a red error message when it tries to build.

Does you have a resource that you have called 1.png 1.gif 1.mp4?

You cannot have resources that have a filename of a number.

Comment: No, I don't have resources with names like number.